# Python rebooting windows using win32

Tags: python, winapi, reboot

I was just learning win32 modules and i try to reboot windows based on [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-December/008481.html) but it doesn't work.
This is the code:

```
import win32security
import win32api
import sys
import time
from ntsecuritycon import *

def AdjustPrivilege(priv, enable=1):
    # Get the process token
    flags = TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY
    htoken =win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), flags)
    # Get the ID for the system shutdown privilege.
    idd = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, priv)
    # Now obtain the privilege for this process.
    # Create a list of the privileges to be added.
    if enable:
        newPrivileges = [(idd, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
    else:
        newPrivileges = [(idd, 0)]
    # and make the adjustment
    win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken,0,newPrivileges)

def RebootServer(message='Rebooting', timeout=30,bForce=0,bReboot=1):
    AdjustPrivilege(SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME)
    try:
        win32api.InitiateSystemShutdown(None,message,timeout,bForce,bReboot)
    finally:
        # Now we remove the privilege we just added.
        AdjustPrivilege(SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, 0)

def AbortReboot():
    AdjustPrivilege(SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME)
    try:
        win32api.AbortSystemShotdown(None)
    finally:
        AdjustPrivilege(SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RebootServer()
    time.sleep(10)
    print ('Aborting shutdown')
    AbortReboot()
```

I use python 3.4 version and my OS is windows 7(64)
and i get this error:

```
pywintypes.error: (1116, 'AbortSystemShutdown', 'Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.')
```

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Does it work for anyone?

Comment: Works fine on my machine (Win7 64), apart from that there's a typo in `AbortReboot()` (`AbortSystemShotdown`)so that aborting the shutdown didn't work and my machine rebooted accidentily. Perhaps it's a permission issue on your machine? Is there an entry in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: @sb9 I think it's a permission issue too. about event log, i don't think so! should i create event log for python?

Comment: No, just take a look into the Windows Event Log (eventvwr.exe). Does yout python program run from a user account with administrative rights?

Comment: Works with a standard (non admin) user as well on my machine

Comment: So the code is correct something is wrong with my system